# Slideshow flickering image on :hover

Tags: html, css, image, hover, slideshow

I'm creating some sort of slideshow. When you hover over an image the image will expand and overlap the other images. But when this happens I still want those images behind the expanded image to work when hovering over their area.

Right now it almost works perfectly, only the expanded image is flickering when you hover over it. I don't want that. How can I solve this?

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3x4K3/)**

**HTML:**

```
<div id="expand">
    <div class="expand_1">
        <figure></figure>
    </div>
    <div class="expand_2">
        <figure></figure>
    </div>
    <div class="expand_3">
        <figure></figure>
    </div>
    <div class="expand_4">
        <figure></figure>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#expand {
    height: 200px;
}

.expand_1 {
    width: 100px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
}

.expand_1 figure {
    width: 100px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
    background: grey;
}

.expand_1 figure:hover {
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    pointer-events: none;
    background: grey;
}

.expand_2 {
    width: 100px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
}

.expand_2 figure {
    width: 100px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
    background: black;
}

.expand_2 figure:hover {
    margin-left: -100px; 
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    pointer-events: none;
    background: black;
}

.expand_3 {
    width: 100px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
}

.expand_3 figure {
    width: 100px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
    background: green;
}

.expand_3 figure:hover {
    margin-left: -200px; 
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    pointer-events: none;
    background: green;
}

.expand_4 {
    width: 100px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
}

.expand_4 figure {
    width: 100px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
    background-color: blue;
}

.expand_4 figure:hover {
    margin-left: -300px; 
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    pointer-events: none;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**Working DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/3x4K3/3/)

Don't use `pointer-events: none;` It is causing the flickering effect. It is also not supported by old IE browsers.

Hover on `div` instead of `figure`:

```
.expand_1:hover figure
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answer.

I came up with the idea when I was looking at this page: [http://www.f-i.com/google/ramayana/](http://www.f-i.com/google/ramayana/). Halfway that page there is an example of what I'm trying to accomplish.

Is there another (easy) way to accomplish this? Without JS?

Comment: @Midwoud Check out the second demo which used an alternative CSS approach.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That works like a charm. But when I want it to work in all web-browsers the only way to get it working is with JS?